# Hidden projects in JIRA

Tags: project, jira

Is it possible to create a project and keep it hidden from others adminirators?

I created one, removed all roles permissions, but it still can be seen in General/Projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not it is not possible.

JIRA Administrators see all projects which makes sense as if you are administrating a system, you should be able to see everything.